# Could " we'd better .." be replaced with " we will .." in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, differences, ambiguity

" I reckon we'd better hit some water tomorrow"

Or

" I reckon we will hit some water tomorrow"

I have two more questions .

Is the word " better " adverb here and if the answer is yes, could it mean "more likely" ?

Comment: You don't give a context for the remark, but _we had better do X_ means 'it would be advisable for us to do X', while _we will_ is simply a prediction that it will happen. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/had-better

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the first sentence here acceptable and meaninful? And could it be an irony or sarcasm  or could we say that this sentence means something like this: i reckon we would be better if we come across some water tomorrow? Or we should/had to hit some water tomorrow?

Comment: _I don't know_ how meaningful it is because, as I said, you don't give any context. I'm _guessing_ that it is said by a traveller in some wild place when the party's water supplies are running low, so they need to find a source of fresh water. It could be ironic understatement for "We really need to  find some water".

Comment: Schneider nodded. “We can make one more day on that, I figure. It’ll be a mite dry, but we should make one more day.”
Miller said, “I figure one more day.”
“If we don’t come across some water,” Schneider said.
“If we don’t come across some water,” Miller agreed.Schneider lifted his tin cup and drained the last dreg of coffee from it. In the firelight, his raised chin and throat bristled and quivered. His voice was cool and lazy. “I reckon we’d better hit some water tomorrow.”
“We’d better,” Miller said. Then: “There’s plenty of water; it’s just there for the finding.”

Comment: @Kate Yes, I think the 'need to' sense is in play here.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had put all that in your original question - and told us the source of the quotation. It seems I guessed right about the situation.

Comment: I thought the question should be short and concise so i didn't write them all and the source of the quatation  is  a novel by john williams ( Butcher's Crossing) .thanks again

Comment: In standard AmE, you would not say "reckon" or "hit water," except in restricted contexts and even then it usually sound like colorful dialect.  I would expect to hear it in a Cowboy movie to mean that their future journey or digging efforts would hopefully intersect with a source of water.  The expression "....(ha)d better is a normal idiom in standard AmE and indicates a future state that must be reached to avoid bad consequences.  "I reckon we will..." means "According to my assessment,we wil....."

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.I agree with your assumption and apart what you said this character ( schneider) speaks german too and doesn't use auxiliary verb sometimes and some things like these.